# How to remove the Toyota Aygo Now windshield wiper

Tags: toyota, windshield-wipers, replace

I've been trying to replace the windshield wiper of a Toyota Aygo Now, but it seems that I cannot even remove the old one.

There are several bits that look like tabs that can be pressed / pushed / moved by a few millimeters, but none of them releases the wiper from the hook.

I've searched Toyota forums, Youtube and Google to no avail. The user manual of the Aygo helpfully explains how to *operate* the wipers, thanks a lot.

If the image below is clear enough, can anybody point to the part that releases this infernal contraption?

[image: photo of windshield and wiper]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I think they are so difficult to remove because, in the old days, a wiper flying off meant a big curved scratch in your windshield.

Comment: @John Canon, actually it wasn't hard once I knew what to do. My irritation is directed at Toyota's engineers who left the user without a single clue about the correct procedure. In pre-Youtube (and pre-SE) days, the only solution would have been to bring the car to the mechanic and throw some euros into his wallet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be fairly easy. You have a hook type arm connector. Turn the blade so it is perpendicular to the arm, then pull the whole thing back towards the base of the arm. It should pop free with a little bit of pressure on it. The plastic part which is fit inside of the hook will go with the wiper.

[Here is a short video by ChrisFix](https://youtu.be/oeezwXQC-mc) which describes the procedure.

Comment: The fun with those old-style wiper fixings is trying to get the new one back on exactly the same way round. For some reason, it always used to take me two attempts, & I've always considered my geo-spatial awareness to be pretty good;) Also, the one he takes out in the video doesn't have a spring clip, the one he puts back does - need to check if there's a trigger clip release, or it's a fight.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Good points. I usually find just a little bit of persuasion with or without pressing the little clip usually gets the job done. They really don't make them very sturdy ;)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing happen on one of my cars. As much as I tried to press the tab to release the wiper it would not come off. What I ended up doing was taking a long nose pliers and since the piece was plastic and was going to be thrown away anyhow I just broke the plastic piece by piece until it came off.  Then I just put on the replacement wiper.